# How to call a function on list item swipe on either left or right side in ionic mobile app

Tags: angularjs, frameworks, ionic-framework

I want to delete list item on left swipe.

How to call a function on list item swipe on either left or right side in ionic mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

`bower` install random socket.io angular-socket-io

```
<script src="lib/sio-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>

<script src="lib/random/lib/random.min.js"></script>


(function(){
  angular.module('starter')
    .controller('CallController', ['$scope', '$state', '$timeout', '$ionicModal', 'SocketService', CallController]);

    function CallController($scope, $state, $timeout, $ionicModal, SocketService){
    ...
    }

})();
```